# SNMP response is null [SNMP4j]

Tags: java, communication, snmp

I've hit kind of a brick wall. I got a small system that communicate with DSLAM's by SNMP. 
Everything has worked fine for a couple of months, but when I recently added a new DSLAM to the system, I couldn't get an answer from it. Tried the other IP's and didn't have a problem.

After an hour or so, suddenly on of the other DSLAM's stopped answering me too. So now I've got two units without any communication, which kinda sucks. So of course I checked the units, and didn't find a problem. By my MIB-browser, I can reach all of the units... But not via my software. So the error lies somewhere in my software. So I checked Wireshark, and see that the getNext requests are going out, but I don't seem to get an answer. When I do it via the MIB browser, there comes an answer. But the funny thing is: the two requests are identical. So I must not be listening - and yes, it is listening.

Why in the world is this specific to some IP's, and dear Lord why do they contaminate eachother?

Let's look at some code:

```
public String GetNextValue(String OID, Dslam dslam) throws IOException {
    Snmp snmp = new Snmp(new DefaultUdpTransportMapping());
    snmp.listen();

    CommunityTarget target = initializeTarget(dslam);

    PDU request = new PDU();
    request.setType(PDU.GETNEXT);
    OID oid= new OID(OID);
    request.add(new VariableBinding(oid));

    PDU responsePDU=null;
    ResponseEvent responseEvent;
    responseEvent = snmp.send(request, target);

    if (responseEvent != null){
        System.out.println("resonse event not null..");
        responsePDU = responseEvent.getResponse();

        if ( responsePDU != null){                
            System.out.println("pdu not null..");
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Vector <VariableBinding> tmpv = (Vector<VariableBinding>) responsePDU.getVariableBindings();

            if(tmpv != null){       
                System.out.println("tmpv not null..");

                VariableBinding vb = (VariableBinding) tmpv.get(0);
                if(!vb.isException()){
                    return vb.getVariable().toString()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    _errorHandler.criticalError("Response error in DSLAM communication");
    return null;
}
```

And the initializer:

```
private CommunityTarget initializeTarget(Dslam dslam){
    Address addr = new UdpAddress(dslam.getAddress() + "/" + dslam.getManagementPort() );
    System.out.println("IP: " + dslam.getAddress() + " port: " + dslam.getManagementPort());
    CommunityTarget target = new CommunityTarget(addr, new OctetString("public"));
    target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version2c);
    target.setTimeout(3000);
    target.setRetries(3);

    return target;
}
```

And if we run a test upon a working DSLAM:

```
@Test
public void Lowtest() throws IOException{
    SnmpController snmpController = SnmpController.GetInstance();

    DslamGrabber dslamGrabber = new DslamGrabber();
    Dslam dslam = dslamGrabber.getByDslamId("test5xda5");

    String result = snmpController.GetNextValue(".1.3.6.1.4.1.637.61.1.39.3.3.1.1.2", dslam);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Result:

```
IP: 195.215.96.135 port: 161
resonse event not null..
pdu not null..
tmpv not null..
OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.637.61.1.39.3.3.1.1.2.1 
BF512_2048
```

The we try against test5xda9 (the second one to succumb to this hideous disease-like error)

We get 3 retries in Wireshark, and the following output:

```
IP: 192.215.96.139 port: 161
resonse event not null..
Response error in DSLAM communication 
null
```

I really hope somebody here can help me. I'm a few hours away to either break down in tears or break a DSLAM..

Best regards
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as a friend pointed out 192 does not equal 195.